# control flask-cache'ing from a view

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-cache

I am wondering if there is a way to allow the user to control the caching properties of a given view  using [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/).

For example, I would like for a view to be cached indefinitely unless the user clicks a `reload` link, in which case the view would be re-generated. I noticed there is an `unless` kwarg available to [@cached](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.cached) decorator, but I am not sure how one would use this.

It seems that I should be able to add a `url_for('this_view', dont_cache=True)` somewhere on `this_view`'s Jinja template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *clear* the cache; given a view function and the full path to the route, use:

```
from flask import current_app

with current_app.test_request_context(path=path):
    # the cache key can use `request` so we need to provide the correct
    # context here
    cache_key = view.make_cache_key()

cache.delete(cache_key)
```

Here `path` is the path to the view; you could use `path = url_for('this_view')` to generate it, and `view` is the (decorated) function object you used `@cache.cached()` on. `cache` is the Flask-Cache object.

Once the cache is cleared, a new request to that view will re-generate it.

If you never set a custom `key_prefix` (callable or string) then the default cache key for a given view is based on the `request.path` value; you could use this too:

```
cache_key = 'view/{}'.format(url_for('this_view'))
cache.delete(cache_key)
```

but the `current_app.test_request_context` / `view.make_cache_key()` dance above will make your cache key re-generation more robust.

Comment: i apologize, but i dont understand exactly how to use your suggestion. it may be obvious, but i am new to flask.

Comment: @alex: you'd use this in a separate view; one that you'd call to clear the cache for the cached view.

Comment: ok i see. so your solution is to use  'redirect' view in the middle?  link on view1 -> redirect view (deletes cache)-> new view1

Comment: @alex: not really, if view1 is entirely cached for all possible route parameters, then that means it won't issue a redirect unless that was the cached response to begin with. How you steer your users to the cache clearing view is something you still have to work out.

Comment: @alex: I picked the code in this answer from a recent project where a backend API lets someone clear the cache if backend data has changed; this way the normal views are all heavily cached and highly performant, until the owners of the backend API send a signal that the data on which the view has been based has changed.

Comment: my application is essentially identical. a view is expensive to generate, but want the user to be able to re-generate if they desire. so i have a  'cache clearing view' which redirects the user to the view, and thus re evaluates the original view function.

Comment: what was you solution for indefinite cache timeout? just a large number for `CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`?

Comment: @alex: That'd work for 'near' indefinite, yes. Take into account that many backends do not guarantee that the value is going to be cached for that long, just that it won't be cached for longer.